# Buying an IP address from Morocco and assigning it to an AWS server?

Tags: ip

Due to some restrictions of a service, I can only login from a Morrocan IP address.

Is it possible to get a Morrocan IP address and assign it to a VPN proxy that I created on AWS using an elastic IP adresss?

Comment: You'd have to buy a /24 block (256 addresses) in order to advertise the addresses on the Internet.  I imagine that'd be too expensive for your purposes.

Comment: just connect from morroco to the instamce trough vpn, try to use port 443 i. e. on openvpn

Comment: Ron Trunk, this is not a money issue

Comment: @RonTrunk comment may be misleading in as much as you dont need to route the morocco IPs and indeed that could be counterproductive.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an EC2 VPN router and connect to this. (Using, for example OpenVPN). You will need to configure it for NAT, forwarding and advertise/configure the route, but this is all quite doable. You might also need to do MTU clamping.

Unfortunately, I dont believe AWS currently have a DC in Morocco, so you may need to navigate that.  An alternative might be to use another company that provides VPS/Virtual machines in Morocco.

Comment: what does dc stand for?
I just want to buy IP addresses from Morocco and not have anything to do with any vps there.

Comment: DC is a data Center. What I'm saying is AWSvdoes not have equipment, so they likely can't provide a Morocco IP.